# CSS Height not 100%

Tags: css, height, positioning

I have checked a lot of other questions similar to this, but it seems no solution works. I have a website that has a body, then an inner div called content. I have tried:

```
body
{
    height: 100%;
}

content
{
    height: 100%;
}
```

AND

```
body
{
}

content
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

which were the answers to most of the questions. but for some reason it is not working for us. When we do the forcing with the absolute positioning, it stretches to more than the page length and also pushes our content to the left when we want it centered (using margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto;)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Number one would be that content isn't an element. That either needs to be an id: #content, or a class: .content. But there's probably more going on.

Comment: It was a #content. I just didn't notate that in the question. Sorry for the confusion! I should have done that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set html to 100% height in addition to body, and your div, e.g.

```
html, body, div{
   height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I had forgotten that there was an html tag to style. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body
{
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#content
{
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Works fine. Attribute `background: red;` is for testing.

Comment: I had already tried that and it didn't work. The solution above was I forgot to set HTML to 100% as well.